# Python change format of a list with strings to floats in a column

Tags: python, string, list, format

Change list with strings

Tried `np.array` :

```
with open(file_to_open) as f:
    for line in f:
        # split the line
        line = line.strip()
        columns = line.split(",")
        if columns[0] == "1":
               x_train.append(line)
        if columns[0] == "2":
             y_train.append(line)
                #print(line, end='')
        print( x_train)
```

I get this result:

```
['1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065', '1,13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1050', '1,13.16,2.36,2.67,18.6,101,2.8,3.24,.3,2.81,5.68,1.03,3.17,1185', '1,14.37,1.95,2.5,16.8,113,3.85,3.49,.24,2.18,7.8,.86,3.45,1480', '1,13.24,2.59,2.87,21,118,2.8,2.69,.39,1.82,4.32,1.04,2.93,735', '1,14.2,1.76,2.4 ....]
```

But I would like to have in this way:

```
1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065
1,13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1050
1,13.16,2.36,2.67,18.6,101,2.8,3.24,.3,2.81,5.68,1.03,3.17,1185
1,14.37,1.95,2.5,16.8,113,3.85,3.49,.24,2.18,7.8,.86,3.45,1480
1,13.24,2.59,2.87,21,118,2.8,2.69,.39,1.82,4.32,1.04,2.93,735
1,14.2,1.76,2.45,15.2,112,3.27,3.39,.34,1.97,6.75,1.05,2.85,1450
1,14.39,1.87,2.45,14.6,96,2.5,2.52,.3,1.98,5.25,1.02,3.58,1290
1,14.06,2.15,2.61,17.6,121,2.6,2.51,.31,1.25,5.05,1.06,3.58,1295
1,14.83,1.64,2.17,14,97,2.8,2.98,.29,1.98,5.2,1.08,2.85,1045
1,13.86,1.35,2.27,16,98,2.98,3.15,.22,1.85,7.22,1.01,3.55,1045
1,14.1,2.16,2.3,18,105,2.95,3.32,.22,2.38,5.75,1.25,3.17,1510
1,14.12,1.48,2.32,16.8,95,2.2,2.43,.26,1.57,5,1.17,2.82,1280
1,13.75,1.73,2.41,16,89,2.6,2.76,.29,1.81,5.6,1.15,2.9,1320
```

That is a part of the txt file a load:

1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065
1,13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1050
1,13.16,2.36,2.67,18.6,101,2.8,3.24,.3,2.81,5.68,1.03,3.17,1185
1,14.37,1.95,2.5,16.8,113,3.85,3.49,.24,2.18,7.8,.86,3.45,1480
1,13.24,2.59,2.87,21,118,2.8,2.69,.39,1.82,4.32,1.04,2.93,735
1,14.2,1.76,2.45,15.2,112,3.27,3.39,.34,1.97,6.75,1.05,2.85,1450
1,14.39,1.87,2.45,14.6,96,2.5,2.52,.3,1.98,5.25,1.02,3.58,1290
1,14.06,2.15,2.61,17.6,121,2.6,2.51,.31,1.25,5.05,1.06,3.58,1295

Comment: Show a sample of `file_to_open`.

Comment: print (','.join(x_train))

Comment: So, you don't want to create a string array. What type do you want on output? String of lines or something like this?

Comment: I dont know what to call this format. i like to have lines with the numbers. no lists, no strings.

Comment: So you want to print the txt file as it is?

Comment: `print(line)`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that all elements in list are numbers and no other alphabetic values, you could tweak your code to transfrom type of strings to floats with the following line:

```
[float(element) for element in columns]
```

In your code you can use it like so:

```
if columns[0] == "1":
    x_train.append([float(element) for element in columns])

if columns[0] == "2":
    y_train.append([float(element) for element in columns])
```

Comment: I tried . Got this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ',' and yes there are only decimal numbers and numbers in the file

Comment: i made an edit, copy again and try. I used `line` instead of `columns`

Comment: Thanks for your help but i get this now :(: [[1.0, 14.23, 1.71, 2.43, 15.6, 127.0, 2.8, 3.06, 0.28, 2.29, 5.64, 1.04, 3.92, 1065.0], [1.0, 13.2, 1.78, 2.14, 11.2, 100.0, 2.65, 2.76, 0.26, 1.28, 4.38, 1.05, 3.4, 1050.0], [1.0, 13.16, 2.36, 2.67, 18.6, 101.0, 2.8, 3.24, 0.3, 2.81, 5.68, 1.03, 3.17, 1185.0], [1.0, 14.37, 1.95, 2.5, 16.8, 113.0, 3.85, 3.49, 0.24, 2.18, 7.8, 0.86, 3.45, 1480.0], [1.0, 13.24, 2.59, 2.87, 21.0, 118.0, 2.8, 2.69, 0.39, 1.82, 4.32, 1.04, 2.93, 735.0], [1.0, 14.2, 1.76, 2.45, 15.2, 112.0, 3.27, 3.39, 0.34, 1.97, 6.75, 1.05,  .....

Comment: ? You get a list of lists. What is your desired output?

Comment: Im quite new to python. I dont like to have lists at all and no strings, just a row of numbers like this:1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065
1,13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1050. Sorry if my explanation is not that detailed

Comment: Then you'll need to define how you want to store this data. If you want to multiple lines of code stored into 1 variable (in your case `x_train`) I think lists are most straight forward method

Comment: Ok now a tried my function which calculate the difference between to points and it seems to work:def get_distance(data1, data2):
    points = zip(data1, data2)
    diffs_squared_distance = [pow(a - b, 2) for (a, b) in points]
    return math.sqrt(sum(diffs_squared_distance))

get_distance(x_train[0], x_train[1])

Comment: If it works, consider accepting the answer and upvoting. If you have further questions it's better to ask new questions so others with similar questions can find the answers as well or google if there are already answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending strings to a list, so what you get back is, unsurprisingly, a list of strings. You don't make it clear how you are *using* an `np.array` - I can see no sign of one in your code - and neither do you make it obvious what actual data format you want.

I have therefore assumed that you would like a list of lists in your `x_train` and `y_train` variables. Instead of appending the line, append a list of columns converted to floats:

```
    ...
    x_train.append([float(x) for x in columns])
    ...
    y_train.append([float(x) for x in columns])
    ...
```

It should then be quite easy to convert `x_train` and `y_train` into numpy nd_arrays, or print each line in the format you want it ...

Comment: i tried . Got this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ','

Comment: In which case your data appears to be different from what you show in the question, or you have made some mistake entering the code. I suspect the latter, since I am at a loss as to how `columns = line.split(',')` can give a value with a comma in it.

Answer (score 0):

Since, it looks like a comma separated file, you can try:

```
data = ps.read_csv('train.txt', header=None)
x_train = data[data.iloc[:,0]==1]
y_train = data[data.iloc[:,0]==2]
```

If you want from your code, just try this:

```
np.array(list(map(float, ','.join(s).split(',')))).reshape(len(x_train),14)
```